# Figuras geométricas como los trazos del patrón de seguridad de un móvil

Tags: python, matplotlib

Qué función de matplotlib me permitiría obtener un listado de figuras obtenidas a partir de la unión de 9 puntos tal como el patrón de seguridad de un móvil.

Answer (score 2):

Que yo sepa no hay una función tan específica, pero puedes programarla tú.

Por ejemplo, si tienes una lista de coordenadas tales como

```
coordenadas = [ (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3) ]
```

Esas serían las coordenadas de cada uno de los 9 puntos. Puedes reordenarlas como quieras, por ejemplo haciendo un `random.shuffle()` de esa lista.

Una vez reordenadas las puedes separar en dos listas `x` e `y` con algo como:

```
y, x = zip(*coordenadas)
```

y pasarle esas listas a `plt.plot(x, y)` lo cual dibujaría el patrón.

Hagamos una función con esto.

```
def dibujar_patron(coordenadas, ax=None):
  y, x = zip(*coordenadas)
  if not ax:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 2))
  ax.plot(x, y, "o-")
  ax.axis("off")
```

Probemos con un patrón en secuencia:

```
coord = [ (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3) ]
dibujar_patron(coord)
```

[image: Imagen]

Ahora con un patrón aleatorio:

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(coord)
dibujar_patron(coord)
```

[image: Otro patron]

Si quisieras generar todos los patrones posibles tendrías que hacer todas las permutaciones de la lista. Pero cuidado! el número de ellas es muy alto. Sería el factorial de 9, que son 362880 patrones "diferentes". En realidad no son tan diferentes porque la mayoría son rotaciones de otros. Si además la figura no diferencia entre el nodo inicial y el final, muchos patrones parecerán indistinguibles (por ejemplo, el que recorre los números en secuencia 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 se verá igual que el que los recorre al revés 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1.

Un ejemplo de cómo generar unos cuantos diferentes, por ejemplo los 16 primeros:

```
from itertools import permutations

# Lista de coordenadas
coord = [ (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3) ]

# Creamos una figura con 16 "subplots" ordenados en 4x4
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4, figsize=(5,5))
fig.tight_layout()

# Obtener las referencias a los 16 subplots en una sola lista plana
axes = [ x for fila in ax for x in fila ]

# Obtener las permutaciones, numerándolas para saber a qué
# subplot va cada una y para poder parar cuando hayamos
# pintado las 16 primeras
for i, variacion in enumerate(permutations(coord)):
  dibujar_patron(variacion, ax=axes[i])
  if i == 15:
    break
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

**Nota** las dos primeras se ven iguales pero no lo son. La primera recorre los puntos del 1 al 9 en orden correlativo. La segunda en cambio pasa del 7 al 9 para luego regresar al 8. Sin embargo la línea "se pisa a sí misma" y por eso se ve así.

## Bonus

No sé si el objetivo era dibujar simplemente la línea quebrada que se mostró en los ejemplos anteriores, o si quieres algo más sofisticado. Por si acaso, aquí tienes otra idea:

```
def dibujar_patron_mejor(secuencia, ax=None):
  coord = [ (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3) ]
  if not ax:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))

  # Pintar circulos con numeros
  for n, (y,x) in enumerate(coord):
    ax.add_patch(Circle((x,y), .4, facecolor="#d0d0d0", edgecolor="black"))
    ax.text(x, y, str(n+1), fontsize="xx-large", ha="center", va="center")

  # Extraer coordenadas de la secuencia
  y, x = zip(*[coord[i-1] for i in secuencia ])

  # Poner amarillo el circulo de salida
  ax.add_patch(Circle((x[0],y[0]), .3, facecolor="#ffffd0", edgecolor="black"))

  # Pintar líneas entre números

  ax.plot(x,y, "-")
  ax.axis("off")
```

En este caso a la función se le pasa ya directamente la secuencia de dígitos a recorrer, en lugar de las coordenadas. La propia función calcula las coordenadas de cada dígito. Ejemplo de uso:

```
dibujar_patron_mejor([3, 5, 2, 1, 8, 9, 6, 7, 4])
```

[image: Patron mejor]

Comment: Siempre con respuestas impecables. +1

Comment: @Adrián Gracias!